# Shortcut to move the cursor to certain characters in Webstorm

Tags: webstorm

I've seen several videos where the user is using Webstorm and hits a keyboard shortcut which brings up a small input field that the user can type a letter, number or other character into. Webstorm then presents the user with several choices denoted by "A", "B", "C", etc. which the user can then type the value of to move to the appropriate spot in the file that is currently being edited. I've searched through Webstorm's shortcuts, but I don't see anything to this effect. Does anyone know what this shortcut is?

I can try to get a screen shot if my explanation wasn't clear enough.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is AceJump plugin - the easiest way to get it - go to Settings-Plugins click on Browse Repository and search for AceJump. Once you install it - the hardest thing for me was to force myself to use it after 2 months - I even type documents in webstorm and then copy it to Word.

Repository is here
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7086

Github is here
https://github.com/johnlindquist/AceJump

Good luck :-)

Comment: Excellent. This is going to save me a lot of time. Thank you!